# SSRS: Custom parameter layout was removed from the report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, sql-server-2014

When I add a parameter to my report, add it to the query and used it in a calculated field, running the report gives me this error:

> "Custom parameter layout was removed from the report. SQL Server 2014
>   Reporting Services and earlier do not support custom parameter
>   layout."

My report runs but returns no rows, just column headers.

My parameter is of type Date/Time

My query is:

```
    SELECT HD_QUEUE.NAME as qname, HD_TICKET.ID, HD_TICKET.CREATED, HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED, CUSTOMER.FULL_NAME as custfullname, 
 HD_STATUS.NAME as statname, HD_TICKET.TITLE, left(ASSIGNEE.FULL_NAME, 40) as assignee, 
 HD_PRIORITY.NAME as pname, HD_CATEGORY.NAME as catname
FROM  HD_TICKET 
 INNER JOIN HD_QUEUE
ON HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = HD_QUEUE.ID
INNER JOIN USER CUSTOMER
ON HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID=CUSTOMER.ID
INNER JOIN USER ASSIGNEE
ON HD_TICKET.OWNER_ID=ASSIGNEE.ID 
 INNER JOIN HD_STATUS 
 ON (HD_TICKET.HD_STATUS_ID=HD_STATUS.ID) 
 AND (HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID=HD_STATUS.HD_QUEUE_ID)
INNER JOIN HD_PRIORITY
ON HD_TICKET.HD_PRIORITY_ID = HD_PRIORITY.ID
  and HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = HD_PRIORITY.HD_QUEUE_ID
  INNER JOIN HD_CATEGORY
ON HD_TICKET.HD_CATEGORY_ID = HD_CATEGORY.ID
and HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = HD_CATEGORY.HD_QUEUE_ID
left join ASSET on ASSET.ID = HD_TICKET.ASSET_ID
left join ASSET_DATA_6 on ASSET.ASSET_DATA_ID = ASSET_DATA_6.ID
WHERE HD_STATUS.NAME = 'Closed'
AND HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED > DATE_SUB(@date_param, INTERVAL 34 DAY)
AND HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED <= @date_param;
```

And my calculated field is:

```
=IIf(Fields!closed_date.Value > (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -6, Parameters!date_param.Value)), "Week 1",
IIf(Fields!closed_date.Value > (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -13, Parameters!date_param.Value)), "Week 2",
IIf(Fields!closed_date.Value > (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -20, Parameters!date_param.Value)), "Week 3",
IIf(Fields!closed_date.Value > (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -27, Parameters!date_param.Value)), "Week 4",
"Week 5"))))
```

Comment: what version of reporting services are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.5.6

Comment: That is what you are using to develop the report.. what about reporting services server? Is it 2008/ R2, 2012, 2014 or 2016?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014

Comment: Though so much.. only in 2016 on wards you are allowed to move the location of parameters. so if you deploy the report against a 2008 server, you will get this error. Did you rearrange your parameters when you developed the report on VS2017? BTW.. the error has nothing to do with your calculated field.

Comment: I didn't move anything around. I only just created the parameter, added it to my query, and added it to my calculated field.